# Encfs mount problem

Tags: 14.04, encfs

After a couple of years of working perfectly I can no longer get access to my folders under Gnome Encfs Manager. After typing in my password I receive this message "The mount folder is not empty". I do not know what this means or what I should do about it. Can anyone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd eliminate the [Gnome EncFS manager](https://moritzmolch.com/apps/gencfsm/) (not related to `cryptkeeper`) first. Try mounting the EncFS folder using the terminal & `encfs` directly, and **verify that the mountpoint folder (exaple here `~/empty-mountpoint-folder`) is actually empty** beforehand (your error message sounds like the mount folder has some other files/folders in it, but I'm not familiar enough with it to blindly trust it):

```
encfs ~/.encrypted-folder ~/empty-mountpoint-folder
```

Or even using the `-v` verbose and `-f` foreground option to make sure *"any
           warning/debug log messages will be displayed on standard error.  In the default
           (background) mode, all log messages are logged via syslog."*:

```
encfs -v -f ~/.encrypted-folder ~/empty-mountpoint-folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find the answer here:
[Unable to mount in cryptkeeper](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1690704)

Usually your encrypted folder will be in your home directory, but will only be visible when mounted (you gave it a name when you created it, probably *encrypted*). Use your file browser to see if the encrypted directory **(not** the seperate .encrypted folder) is visible. If it is (and you cannot access all the files as you usually can) then delete the subfolders inside. Remount with encfs manager and it should work now.